# htaccess rewrite replace part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite part of URLS like:

- http://www.myweb.com/cat1/subcat2/how-to-do-this

to

- http://www.myweb.com/cat2/subcat2/how-to-do-this

there are many urls in which the end part(how-to-do-this) changes

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^cat1/subcat1/(.*) /cat/subcat2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

but this doesn't works.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`R=301` is used for external redirection, if you want to rewrite the request , you can use the following :

```
RewriteRule ^cat1/subcat2/(.*) /cat2/subcat2/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will internally redirect (without changing the url in browser)

- cat1/subcat2/foo

to

- cat2/subcat2/foo

Comment: I tried this - RewriteRule ^cat1/subcat1/(.*) http://mywesite.com/cat2/subcat2 [L,NC] and when i call the url http://mywesite.com/cat1/subcat1/how-to-do-this it redirected me to http://mywesite.com/cat2/subcat2/

Comment: all i want is mywebsite.com/cat1/subcat1/how-to-do-this should redirect to mywesite.com/cat2/subcat2/how-to-do-this